# Time and space complexity of this algorithm for counting nodes in a complete binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have this below code for calculating the number of nodes in a complete binary tree<sup>*</sup> without visiting all the nodes.

```
    public int countNodes(TreeNode root) {
        if(root==null){
            return 0;
        }
        int LH=height(root,false); // depth of leftmost leaf
        int RH=height(root,true);  // depth of rightmost leaf
        if(LH==RH){
            return (int)Math.pow(2,LH)-1;
        }
        else return countNodes(root.left)+countNodes(root.right)+1;
    }

    int height(TreeNode root,boolean lr){
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        if(lr==false)
            return 1+height(root.left,lr);
        return 1+height(root.right,lr);
    }
```

How can I determine the time complexity here? I'm confused  the nodes are visited more than once.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>*Complete binary tree*: all the levels of the tree are filled completely except the lowest level nodes which are filled from as left as possible</sub>

Comment: @trincot this is only for a complete binary tree. Let me edit the question

Comment: Which definition of complete you use here? Do you mean all leaves are at the bottom level or at the two bottommost levels?

Comment: All the levels of the tree are filled completely except the lowest level nodes which are filled from as left as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `height` function follows a single path from the current node to a single leaf (either the leftmost, or the rightmost leaf). This has a time complexity of O(ℎ) where ℎ is the height of that node.

When recursion of `countNodes` is needed (because the leftmost leaf is deeper than the rightmost leaf), then we know that in **at most one** of the two recursive calls of `countNodes` this situation will occur again, i.e. where the leftmost leaf is deeper than the rightmost leaf.

So in the worst case the recursive calls of `countNodes` will deepen all the way to a leaf. All other recursive calls of `countNodes` will hit the base case immediately (as there `LH` and `RH` are equal), and those represent two more calls of `height` that can be considered work that is part of the work that was done for the parent node. This way we account for work only on a single path from the root to a leaf.

So taking this all together we have O(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + log). This is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and thus we have O(log(1+log)/2) = O(log²).

The space complexity is trivial: each new variable that this code allocates takes constant space, so the recursion stack is the determining factor: O(log).